# JavaFX set margins for items in GridPane

Tags: java, javafx, layout, gridpane

I am trying to get some better layout and for that I would like to `setMargin` for my items inside a `GridPane`. This is what I tried (only for the first `idLabel, idTextField, nameLabel, nameTextField` for testing):

```
private Pane createCenterPane() {   
    centerGridPane = new GridPane();
    
    centerGridPane.add(createIdLabel(), 0, 0);
    centerGridPane.add(createIdTextField(), 2, 0);
    BorderPane.setMargin(idLabel, new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
    BorderPane.setMargin(idTextField, new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
    
    centerGridPane.add(createNameLabel(), 0, 1);
    centerGridPane.add(createNameTextField(), 2, 1);
    BorderPane.setMargin(nameLabel, new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
    BorderPane.setMargin(nameTextField, new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
    
    centerGridPane.add(createDescriptionLabel(), 0, 2);
    centerGridPane.add(createDescriptionTextArea(), 2, 2);
    
    centerGridPane.add(createSeverityLabel(), 0, 3);
    centerGridPane.add(createSeverityComboBox(), 2, 3);
    
    centerGridPane.add(createTypeLabel(), 0, 4);
    centerGridPane.add(createTypeComboBox(), 2, 4);
    
    centerGridPane.add(createDependencyLabel(), 0, 5);
    centerGridPane.add(createDependencyListView(), 2, 5);
    
    return centerGridPane;
}
```

**`createIdLabel` (the other `createsX` work similar)**:

```
private Label createIdLabel() {
    return idLabel = new Label("Id:");
}
```

But `setMargin` doesn't do anything:

[image]

I would like to have some spacing between the "rows" and also between the `label` and the item next to it.

I am quite new to this, so if anything is unclear just let me know! happy for every help!

Comment: Propably looking for `GridPane#setHgap()` and `GridPane#setVgap()`?

Comment: @n247s never used that before. Could you elaborate on that? :)

Comment: That will simply add spacing between each row (vgap) and each column (hgap). Aint that the question? Just try setting both to `5.0` and see what happens.

Comment: yes thats the question. I will give it a try

Comment: @n247s that was it, thanks for your help!

Comment: _Could you elaborate on that?_ you might read the api doc, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

- For margins use `GridPane.setMargin(node, insets)` instead of
  `BorderPane.setMargin(node, insets)`
- For horizontal space between columns use `centerGridPane.setHgap(value)`
- For vertical space between lines use `centerGridPane.setVgap(value)`